# Unity3D: Issues on combining FPS Controller and gyroscope camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, gyroscope

So I'm trying to do something different with the Unity 5 FPS Controller, and have attached a gyroscope camera script I got from here (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/sharing-gyroscope-camera-script-ios-tested.241825/) to the FirstPersonCharacter camera (after commenting out every mouselook-related code in FirstPersonController.cs). Works so far, with FirstPersonCharacter looking around according to the phone's movements, but problems arise when the player starts moving.

The movement of the player(FPSController) and the camera(FirstPersonCharacter) are disconnected, with the player moving and strafing irrespective to the FirstPersonCharacter's transform. This is because only FirstPersonCharacter's transform is affected by the gyro controls, and not FPSController.

I attempted a fix by adding in turn controls to FirstPersonController.cs, where FPSController is merely rotated along the y-axis, and that works, but only for the parent, FPSController. It screws up FirstPersonCharacter, causing it to roll while looking straight, yaw while looking up or down, and pitch while looking to a side, when FPSController turns.

I was hoping that turning the parent would affect the child's behaviour, and it did, but only in a terrible way. Anyone have a solution or an idea to fix this?

Comment: It looks like a local/world rotation problem from here. Could you please provide some code and describe your hierarchy in the scene?

Comment: The code for FirstPersonController.cs is the unedited copy you get from Unity's Standard Assets save for the addition of a couple functions to allow turning the player. As for the hierarchy of my objects, FPSController is the parent of FirstPersonCharacter, and it only rotates along the y-axis. FirstPersonCharacter however rotates along every axis, due to the nature of gyroscopic movement.

Comment: Also, I had forgotten to mention the camera weirdness occurs only when i change:

`transform.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;`

in the above gyroscope camera script to:

`transform.localRotation = Input.gyro.attitude;`

Comment: When using transform.rotation, the camera seemed to try to turn along with the player, but then the gyroscope controls appear to override whatever rotation change it was trying to do, and resets it to its initial rotation. Like. the head keeps looking down and along the same axis while the body turns. And so i used localRotaton in hopes that it would consider the rotation of the parent object, but it only made things worse.

Answer (score 0):

for my player controller i always use this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]

public class SC_FPSController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkingSpeed = 7.5f;
    public float runningSpeed = 11.5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public float lookSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float lookXLimit = 45.0f;

    CharacterController characterController;
    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    float rotationX = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool canMove = true;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        // Lock cursor
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate move direction based on axes
        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
        // Press Left Shift to run
        bool isRunning = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
        float curSpeedX = canMove ? (isRunning ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;
        float curSpeedY = canMove ? (isRunning ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;
        float movementDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
        moveDirection = (forward * curSpeedX) + (right * curSpeedY);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && canMove && characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            moveDirection.y = movementDirectionY;
        }

        // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
        // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
        // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        // Player and Camera rotation
        if (canMove)
        {
            rotationX += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeed;
            rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -lookXLimit, lookXLimit);
            playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to move the camera with the player you have to put the camera as as ubfolders of the player.

I hope i could help!